# Can we do JMS point to point testing which we do in JMeter in Karate Framework

Tags: jmeter, jms, karate, message-queue

Can we setup the JMS point to point setup which is currently done in JMeter from Karate Framework

We can pass .p12 ssl file but how do we pass JNDI properties